# Derivative of a function which is defined as a derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, fractional-calculus

I'm new to this kind of stuff so maybe this is a stupid question but I don't even know what to search on the internet.

My problem is that: find the derivative of the following function on $\Bbb R^3$

$g(x;y)=D^xf(y)$

Where $D^x$ is the x-th derivative of the function $f(y)$ defined on $\Bbb R^2$ (assuming that is continuos and always differentiable). I know that, using fractional calculus, $D^x$ is well defined for every $x\in \Bbb R$ but I don't know if the function I wrote has any sense or which branch of math studies this kind of relations so I don't even know how to start. Any hint ?

Just to make things clearer I make an example:

Take $f(y)=y^2$ as the function, some values would be:

$g(1;y)=2y$

$g(2;y)=2$

$g(3;y)=0$

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of a function on $\mathbb R^3$ is not really a good way to put it. You can take the partial derivative (which is the derivative with respect to a specific variable). In addition, if you have a function defined on $\mathbb R^2$ I don't think trying to find derivatives in $\mathbb R^3$ is going to make much sense (fractional calculus aside).

Having said all of that, if you have a function
$$F=f(y)$$
you can use the derivative operator to find z given...
$$(1) \quad z=D^x \cdot f(y)$$

To answer your question, equations like $(1)$ are studied all the time in mathematics. If you have $z$, but would like $f(y)$ you need integrals and possibly the theory of differential equations. If you have $f(y)$, but would like z, you need the theory of differentiation. If your interested in non-integer derivatives then replace the above subjects with the prefix-"fractional".

Here are some links,
[Intro to Fractional Calculus](http://www.uta.cl/charlas/volumen19/Indice/MAUROrevision.pdf),
[Intro to Fractional Differential Equations](http://jcresson.perso.univ-pau.fr/cresson-adda2.pdf), 
[Interpretation of Fractional Derivative](http://vixra.org/pdf/1206.0005v1.pdf), 
[Geometric Interpretation of Fractional Integration](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.4.3874&rep=rep1&type=pdf). The last link I provided is a bit silly, as it just is a paper about vector projection, it doesn't actually provide physical intuition, it just identifies how one would plot the integral.